# Forward a domain but keep URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, cross-domain, subdomain, white-labelling

I'd like to send `http://app.client-domain.com/` to my Heroku-hosted Rails app at `http://www.my-domain.com/`.

From research it looks like this would be relatively straightforward (with domain record redirects/forwards like A, MX, CName, etc.)

However, I don't want `http://app.client-domain.com/` to just forward the browser to `http://www.my-domain.com`... I want it to appear that the user is still on `http://app.client-domain.com`.

For example, a request to:

`http://app.other-domain.com/user/4`

would be serving data from:

`http://www.my-domain.com/user/4`

... but the URL would remain:

`http://app.other-domain.com/user/4`

Likewise, if a user is sent (via the app) to a new address within the app (like `/products/4`), the scheme above would be maintained. It would truly look like the app lived at

`http://app.other-domain.com/`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. There are two main methods to achieve something like this.

The preferred method would be for the client to use a DNS CNAME that points `app.client-domain.com` to `www.my-domain.com`. Your heroku app, would then have to be configured with the domain `app.client-domain.com`. It should also be configured to not redirect to "primary" domain.

The more problematic way to solve this, is to set up a webserver for `app.client-domain.com` that serves a webpage with frames, where `www.my-domain.com` is then loaded in a frame.

The CNAME approach is by far the preferred way. Using frames gives issues with SSL, and some sites might try to escape being in frames, and will likely also cause PCI compliance issues if you are using payment gateways.